# Azure storage add role assignment AD group via nodejs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, role-based-access-control, azure-node-sdk

How do I add a **new role assignment** to an Azure Storage Blob Container where the role is **Reader** and the member is an Azure AD Group via javascript/nodejs?

I cannot seem to find which SDK to use. I found this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/arm-authorization-profile-2020-09-01-hybrid-readme?view=azure-node-latest), but not sure if it the correct one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking to implement the same logic, here comes my findings.

You need to use `@azure/arm-authorization` to create the client. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/arm-authorization-readme?view=azure-node-preview)

For sample code, check this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-js-samples/tree/main/samples/authorization)